# Unlock computer window XP

Tags: windows-xp

On my Windows XP, once the desktop is locked, when I try to unlock the system, I want to auto populate my username in the unlock computer window. Right now I have to type my username and then password, each and everytime, I unlock my desktop. Is there any way to do this??

Answer (score 0):

Please open Group Policy Editor, go to `\Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options` and check `Interactive logon: Display user information when the session is locked`.

For more Information please look at [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj852183.aspx).

Comment: where can I find Group Policy Editor?

Comment: On Windows XP you can Start/Run/gpedit.msc.

Comment: @shrishail: You are welcome. If my answer was correct, then please accept it. Thanks.